# debezium in podman FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Tags: monitoring, debezium, podman

I have a problem with monitoring debezium. My env - KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/kafka/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8080:/kafka/config.yml don't work correctly
I builded my project on podman 2.2.1 version. with root user.

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failedFATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:47) ... 6 more*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at line: 422## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:## SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6a4143db77, pid=1, tid=606## JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.6+10) (build 11.0.6+10-LTS)# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)# Problematic frame:# C [libc.so.6+0x37b77] abort+0x297## Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to /kafka/app/core.1)## An error report file with more information is saved as:# /kafka/app/hs_err_pid1.log## If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:# http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

On docker my project running good, but i want to use podman. Please help me with some advice

Comment: Hi, I'd recommend you to try it first out of podman/Docker and make sure that the javaagent used iin the image s compatible with Java used in the image

Comment: I have that Dockerfile `FROM debezium/connect:1.2
  
EXPOSE 8083
EXPOSE 19007
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.3.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar > /kafka/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar
COPY config.yml /kafka/config.yml
ENV KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/kafka/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=19007:/kafka/config.yml
ENV JMX_PORT=1977`
And this dockerfile working in docker but don't working in podman. And podman crashed on KAFKA_OPTS env. 
I haven't any ideas

Comment: I used different jmx_exporter.jar and result was didn't change

Comment: So, please again, could you please try it without the podman/Docker first?